# How to get patterns in html input

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a requirement where password field should be in a certain pattern
(# | # | # | #)
So, I have tried this below method.
But I haven't got any output,
 
**screenshot**
[image]
If there are any third party libraries, please provide. My approach

```html
<input type="password" name="passwod" pattren="[0-9]{1}-[0-9]{1}-[0-9]{1}-[0-9]{1}" maxlength="4" /><br><br>

<label>Required input pattern</label>
<input type="text" name="sample" maxlength="7" value="#|#|#|#" />
```

Comment: Which kind of output are you refering to? Have you thought about writing `pattern` without a typo?

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Comment: Hi this might help you https://medium.com/@wowmotty/replace-the-input-password-bullet-1cd4ee34e0aa

Comment: It fells like your requirement is purely tied to UI, meaning the actual password  value should be nothing but a 4 characters string in the end, right ? If it is the case, You can implement such a component using a simple text input and hook into its events so you could 1/ store the real value 2/ process this value to replace characters with hashtag 3/ render the thransformed value in some inline-block element.

Answer (score 0):

a) correct your typo: `pattren` should be `pattern`.

b) `maxlength` should be 7 (because you want to validate 7 characters).

c) (optional but useful) add `^` and `$` to the pattern regex to denote the start and end of the required match.

```html
<input type="password" name="password" pattern="^[0-9]{1}-[0-9]{1}-[0-9]{1}-[0-9]{1}$" maxlength="7" /><br><br>

<label>Required input pattern</label>
<input type="text" name="sample" maxlength="7" value="#|#|#|#" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Visually you can achieve this purely with html and css. I added an quick example for this below. Another option would be to also use javascript, but that can quickly get even more complex.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 95px;
}

.background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #EEE;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.background i {
  width: 1px;
  height: 22px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 16px 12px;
  background-color: #CCC;
}
.background i:first-child {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.password {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 40px;
  letter-spacing: 8px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  color: #AAA;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="background"><i></i><i></i><i></i></div>
  <input class="password" type="password" name="passwod" pattern="[0-9]{1}[0-9]{1}[0-9]{1}[0-9]{1}" maxlength="4">
</div>
```